# 1990s TV series about a family getting stuck in Earth's distant past via a time portal/gate

Tags: story-identification, tv

This is another series I want to watch again, in color this time. When I was watching it it, something broke in my TV and it was showing everything
in B&W :(

I will list everything I remember from it. Hopefully it will be enough.

A family of 4 or 5 people (a father and kids) goes on a holiday. The opening sequence shows them going on a white jeep through some desert. The ground gives way, and they fall into a sinkhole. At the bottom of the sinkhole is a time portal. They drive through and end up in Earth's distant past, in the time when dinosaurs ruled the Earth.

1. They live in a treehouse above ground.
2. They find themselves a pet dinosaur, that is chewing everything he can get his paws on.
3. A bit further in the the jungle live 3 reptilians. They are intelligent and bad-tempered. Their boss has some kind of mind-control crystal
   in a scepter. The family constantly plays tit-for-tat with them.
4. Later on, the father found himself a new girlfriend, some Amazon-looking woman with whom he goes hunting.
5. She introduced him to another reptilian, which looks like upright walking dolphin or amphibian and is not aggressive.
6. Then, someone finds a new friend that looks like a mini-yeti or a primate, Semi-intelligent and also not aggressive.
7. Later in the series, the family finds crude oil and makes crude petrol for their car out of it.
8. After that, they steal crystals from the reptilians' cave, and gets them to power their CD player after all their batteries go flat.
9. Their jeep somehow keeps working without any servicing or spare parts...
10. One of kids find a futuristic laser gun, and the first thing he does with it is go to the reptilians' cave to show them who is now boss in the jungle.
    Then, the pet dino chews it up and it breaks down.

Overall it is a bit primitive, but when you watch something as a kid, it doesn't matter :-)

Comment: Lots of detail here and very easy to identify as a result. Hopefully your others will be similarly informative.

Comment: Wow, a CD player! I thought those came from the Precambrian, not the Mesozoic. You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is [*Land of the Lost*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Lost_(1991_TV_series)) (1991), a remake of the classic [1974 series of the same name](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3m7Xow0YxE).

A family are vacationing in their Jeep Cherokee™ and fall through a portal into the land of the dinosaurs. Hijinks ensue in a vain attempt to get you to buy [plastic tat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvwpWwmadAc) for your children*.

> It featured the Porter family - father Tom, son Kevin and daughter
> Annie - trapped in a parallel universe after their Jeep Cherokee fell
> through a time portal while exploring the back country. They soon meet
> another human, a "beautiful" jungle girl named Christa who came from
> 1960s San Francisco. Christa became trapped in the Land of the Lost
> when she was very young and grew up alone (an earlier concept would
> have featured an adult Holly Marshall as the "mystery girl", along
> with Cha-Ka, but, due to casting, the characters were revisualized as
> Christa and Stink).
>
> The Porters live in a large "treehouse" (although it is actually built
> between a series of large logs and not rooted trees) that the family
> built after they realized their tents provided little safety from
> dangerous dinosaurs. After their first encounter with the Scarface,
> they devised an alarm system by stringing up a series of empty tin
> cans surrounding the treehouse perimeter that would shake and make
> noise if Scarface were to show up again.

*<sub>Accessories sold seperately. Batteries not included. Not a flying toy</sub>

Comment: First thing I thought of when I saw that title was the [2009 movie Land of the Lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Lost_(film)), starring Will Ferrell among others.